# Docker コンテナ内でシステム時間を書き換えても数秒で元の時刻に戻ってしまう

Tags: linux, centos, docker

掲題の通りdateコマンドなどでシステム時間を書き換えても数秒で元の時刻に戻ってしまいます。

環境はDocker for Mac上のCentOS7です。
設定を確認したところ、ntpdはないっておらず、同期設定もされていません。

```
# timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2021-06-08 22:53:27 UTC
      Universal time: Tue 2021-06-08 22:53:27 UTC
      RTC time: Tue 2021-06-08 22:53:27
      Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
      NTP enabled: n/a
      NTP synchronized: no
      RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

Dockerコンテナとして環境を構築してるめ、システム時間がホストと同期されてしまうことが原因だと考えているのですが、
永続的にコンテナ内のシステム時間を変更することはできないものでしょうか？
ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: http://akira-arets.blogspot.com/2020/12/linux-centos7-timezone-ntp.html　こちらの記事は参考になりますでしょうか。

Comment: date コマンドなどでのシステム時間の書き換えは、具体的にどのような操作を行ったのかを質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: 参考: [Time in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284248)